# Десериализация Json в случае, когда свойство может приходить как массив или как значение

Tags: c#, json

Есть Json

```
{"id": 20, "name": "name", "multiple": true, "value":[]}
```

И есть такой Json

```
{"id": 21, "name": "name", "value": ""}
```

Я хочу универсализировать это в тип

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("multiple")]
    public bool IsMultiple { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public string[] Values { get; set; }
}
```

Хочу парсить автоматически

```
var mc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
```

Проблема в том, что когда приходит одно значение, десериализатор не может спарсить это в массив. Как его этому научить?

**UPD:**

Не заработало, кстати. Вот код конвертера, который я вешаю на свойство

```
public class SingleOrArrayConverter : JsonConverter<string[]>
{
    public override string[] ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, string[] existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var res = new List<string>();
        var type = reader.ValueType;
        var flag = true;
        while (flag)
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.String:
                    res.Add(reader.Value.ToString());
                    break;
                case JsonToken.EndObject:
                case JsonToken.StartArray:
                case JsonToken.EndArray:
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            flag = reader.Read();
        }

        return res.ToArray();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, string[] value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

В итоге теперь не работают оба случая. Тесты валятся с ошибкой

> Сообщение: Метод теста
>   TapSyncTests.JsonMappingTests.RmCustomFieldMultipleParseTest создал
>   исключение:  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Unexpected
>   end when deserializing object. Path '', line 1, position 70..

в момент десериализации. Конвертер при этом отрабатывает корректно.

Comment: А если использовать не массив, а List?

Comment: одно значение это именно пустая строка? или может быть любая?

Comment: @ГеннадийП, а какая разница?

Comment: @Grundy, любая. Там стринговое значение

Comment: @iRumba https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432166/how-to-deserialize-a-json-property-that-can-be-two-different-data-types-using-js

Comment: @ГеннадийП, ага, примерно так и сделал

Comment: В `value` приходит либо одна строка, либо массив строк — так? Вам нужно только десериализовать или сериализовать тоже?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужна только десериализация, проще всего написать что-то вроде:

```
public class MyData
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("multiple")]
    public bool Multiple { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public object Value { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string[] Values
        => Multiple
        ? ((JArray)Value).Select(t => (string)((JValue)t).Value).ToArray()
        : new[] { (string)Value };
}
```

Тогда:

```
var json1 = "{\"id\": 20, \"name\": \"name\", \"multiple\": true, \"value\":[\"aaa\", \"bbb\"]}";
var json2 = "{\"id\": 21, \"name\": \"name\", \"value\": \"zzz\"}";
var d1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(json1);
var d2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(json2);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", d1.Values)); // aaa, bbb
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", d2.Values)); // zzz
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Мне не нравится как это выглядит, но оно работает. :)